# How can I describe someone who changes clothes frequently?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Suppose one of your friends puts on different clothes every day. Is there any word or phrase to describe someone like that? I think *luxury* is not very close to that meaning.

Comment: Changing outfits every day is normal behavior. Do you mean someone changes their clothes multiple times in one day?

Comment: If you want to describe her state of mind instead of her vanity you could say 'fickle' or 'irresolute.'

Comment: X "never wears the same clothes/outfit twice" is a common expression, but is 6 words.

Comment: @StuartF That means something different. The person the OP describes wears a garment for a day. The reason they don't wear it the next day might be so that they can wash it before wearing it again on a later day. They might wear it many times over its lifetime. That doesn't mean they never wear it twice.

Comment: You seem to be adding things to the question that aren't there. The OP refers to luxury, "changing clothes frequently" and "different clothes every day". There's nothing about washing clothes. To me the question - especially the mention of luxury - implies having a lot of clothes, being wealthy, possibly never wearing the same thing twice ("different every day" is ambiguous), but not just washing them nightly. Sadly the question is too old to check.

Comment: Yes @StuartF, it looks like someone has anonymously down voted every answer which reads the question this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word that describes this situation is [*excess*](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/excess):

> more than is necessary, reasonable or acceptable

Another [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excess) is:

> the state or an instance of surpassing usual, proper, or specified limits : superfluity

So the adjective form is *excessive*--your friend could be *excessive* because they change their clothes so often. Or, similarly, they change their clothes *excessively*.

Comment: To take a less negative view of it, if they change their clothes often to fit a situation they might be *fashionable* or *stylish*.

Comment: Or "changes her clothes to excess."

Answer (score 4):

My impression is that most women and some men wear different outfits every day.  I doubt that any terms suggestive of excess (like *clothes horse, obsessive, fashionista*) are appropriate.  Regarding whether the friend in question is *fashionable, stylish, vain, fickle,* or *irresolute*, all of those words represent unrelated issues not supported by the question.

If you want non-judgmental words, *normal, ordinary* or *clean* probably are best.  If you want to suggest some extra care for clothes, perhaps use *fastidious*.  If you want to suggest a good deal of extra care for clothes, use some of those previously suggested words.

Answer (score 2):

Another noun expression for such a person is *clothes horse*.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the sense you are looking for [fashionista](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fashionista) might be appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I think the word you're looking for might be *obsessive*.

Answer (score -1):

Fashion victim:

> Someone who is held sway by fashion and feels they must follow every latest trend, even though it may not suit them or is somehow to their detriment. (Jelila)

([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fashion-victim))